# How does nic driver hang and timeout occur?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver, nic

n linux kernel 3.18, if the remaining number of descriptors in the `xmit_frame` function in the nic driver is 0, `netif_stop_subqueue` is executed, `NETDEV_TX_BUSY` is returned, and `netif_wake_subqueue` is executed well in `tx_irq` function part.

`netif_wake_subqueue` does not run on Linux 4.9. The condition to enter `netif_wake_subqueue` is `if (__netif_subqueue_stopped () &&! (Tset_bit () {`.

Which part should I look at? How do I solve the problem?